# Html color codes not showing properly?

Tags: html

I have this line of HTML code for background color:

```
<body bgcolor="#2980B9">
```

I used a hex code generator to pick the color. However, I first used color: "silver" and it came up black. Then "grey" actually resulted in bright green.

I'm on Mac OSX, and had to use the Safari browser to even get the intended colors showing properly.

Comment: That code use is long gone. Use styles instead: `<body style="background-color:#2980B9">`

Comment: Uggh man I should've known! I was using my text which used "body style", then I was using a YouTube tutorial, and just figured it was another was of writing the same thing. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on using `body bgcolor`. I've just tried using it on the latest Chrome and it's not working. In other words, it's deprecated and is not supported anymore.

Use `<body style="background-color: #2980B9">` instead.